# Partially Delivered Email Causes Error in CF10

Tags: coldfusion, smtp

My company just turned on sender validation for the SMTP relay.  So in the old days, I could send an email to nobody@company.com and it would not result in any error.  Now, that email results in this:

```
"Error","scheduler-2","10/31/16","09:04:49",,
"com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException:
250 2.0.0 xxxxxxxx-1 Message accepted for delivery ;
nested exception is: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException:
550 5.1.1 User Unknown on Mail Relay"
```

Is there anything I can do via JVM arguments or anything else to ignore these errors and consider the email sent?  There's a box where we send out 2-3K emails a day and there's about 1K of "undelivered" emails now on a daily basis. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception `SMTPAddressFailedException` is a result of a failed authentication on the mail server, so this is not related to the JVM configuration at all. ColdFusion simply builds mail content and adds it to the mail spooler. Due to the async. nature of a spooler, you cannot catch these errors at runtime.

Your only option is to communicate with the actual mail server before using `cfmail` (and ask if the sender is legit). However, as far as I know there is no built-in function/tag/tool in CF to do so.

Comment: Thanks, Alex.  I was afraid this was the answer... :(